# How to check if all class names of divs in the DOM have a specific string with vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, classname, class-names

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="1hidden1></div>
  <div class="123"></div>
  <div class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

How can I check if a div in the DOM has a class name that contains the text `hidden`? The desired output would be `true` for the above code.

Here is what I have so far, but this only checks for the third div in the example above:

```
if (document.getElementById('app').classList.contains('hidden')) {
  // this does not select the first div within #app
}
```

I would like to check for both the third and first div -- any div that contains a class name with the text `hidden`.

Comment: Consider using GetElementsByTag `var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.querySelectorAll()` and attribute contains selector, check the `.length` of the returned `NodeList` and use `!!` operator to get a `Boolean` value

```js
var hidden = document.querySelectorAll("#app [class*='hidden']");

console.log(!!hidden.length, hidden);
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="1hidden1"></div>
  <div class="123"></div>
  <div class="hidden"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using normal javascript you can use getElementsByTagName and then for each div found, you can check corresponding className

You can check the JSFiddle here:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (i = 0, len = divs.length, text = ""; i < len; i++) { 
    console.log(divs[i].className);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dttw8fcb/

Comment: How does the code at Answer check for specific text within value of `class` of element?

Comment: I have already printed the class name, if for any specific class any specific task needs to be executed, then an if check can be added in the for loop itself